# Does it make sense to compute the KL divergence of two KDEs?

Tags: kernel-smoothing

Does it? I'm not exactly certain. I fit two KDE PDFs on two datasets. I want to measure the disimilarity between them.

Comment: Kl divergence (and other information theoretic quantities) can be estimated directly from the data rather than through KDEs.  See e.g. http://www.tsc.uc3m.es/~fernando/bare_conf3.pdf

Comment: What if the sets differ in size?

Comment: In the paper the number of samples is different, n and m (see first sentence of section 2).

Comment: cool; do you know if this is available in Python?

Comment: something like http://www.isi.edu/~gregv/npeet.html